# Set Change Status Dropdown for all user in Mantis Bug Tracker

Tags: mantis

I added Change Status to Dropdown in my Mantis Bug Tracker. It shows only for particular users. How to Set Change status to Dropdown for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You should set an access threshold by overriding $g_change_view_status_threshold in config_inc.php. By default, this is set to UPDATER. You can change this to REPORTER if you want your issue reporters to change this field. Eg:

```
$g_change_view_status_threshold = REPORTER;
```